# AzureDevOps-YML-pipeline Get PublishBuildArtifacts URL in yml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any possibility to get the URL of a published artifact in the yml pipeline, so it can be used in further pipeline tasks/steps?

Sadly, the Microsoft Docs on the two tasks don't give any hints if the published path value is available in any way.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: report.html
    artifactName: HtmlReport
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're using the artifacts - Deployment jobs will typically automatically download the artifacts into the `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` folder with the same name as you declare in the build task.

So in your case it would be located at `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\HtmlReport`

You can also use the [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to download a specific artifact:

```yaml
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'HtmlReport`
```

This is useful if you have multiple published artifacts and you only want to download one of them in a later stage. There are other options if you wish to download an artifact from a different pipeline.

Note that the [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task is now deprecated and you are recommended to use the newer Publish Pipeline Artifacts and matching Download Pipeline Artifacts tasks:

> We recommend upgrading from **build artifacts** (`PublishBuildArtifacts@1` and `DownloadBuildArtifacts@0`) to **pipeline artifacts** (`PublishPipelineArtifact@1` and `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`) for faster performance.

Comment: i don't have the environment at hand anymore to try this out at the moment, as soon as I have a ado env at hand again I will try. thanks